# Why does this return an empty tuple?

Tags: python, regex

```
s = "hello cats"
print(re.search(r"hello",s).groups())
```

This prints `()`.

According to the documentation, groups() returns an empty tuple if no matches were found. So why doesn't this match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`groups` returns matched **groups**. You did not define any:

```
s = "hello cats"
print(re.search(r"(he)l(lo)",s).groups())
```

prints `('he', 'lo')`

Comment: Oh god, I totally misunderstood this. I get it now. Thanks.